# Laravel Relationship issue with user Model

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using laravel and I am trying to create an relationship with user model

User Table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz |
| 2 | abc |
| 3 | zzz |
| 4 | yyy |

users_teamleaders table

| user_id | team_user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

Inside User Model I have written

```
public function userteamdata()
{
  return $this->hasMany(UserTeamLeaders::class);
}
```

Inside UserTeamLeaders Model I have witten

```
public function distributorUser()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'team_user_id', 'id');
}
```

I want to fetch the details of user with relation user data also

like example
{
'id' : 1,
'name' : 'xyz'
'userteamdata': [
{
'id' : 2,
'name' : 'abc'
},
{
'id' : 3,
'name' : 'zzz'
}
];
}

is there any way out to fetch like this using relation or I have to do it using query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the basic implementation, it can be done something like

```
$user_id = 1;

// Fetch the user with the related 'userteamdata' and the related 'distributorUser' of each 'userteamdata'
$user = User::with('userteamdata.distributorUser')->find($user_id);

// Transform the 'userteamdata' relationship data
$user->userteamdata = $user->userteamdata->map(function ($userTeamLeader) {
    return [
        'id' => $userTeamLeader->distributorUser->id,
        'name' => $userTeamLeader->distributorUser->name,
    ];
});
```